# Get previous location in Angularjs ui-router

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, pushstate, angular-ui-router

I know we can use `fromState` and `fromParams` in the `$stateChangeSuccess` to get all information about previous location. Like said here:

[Angular - ui-router get previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635381/angularjs-ui-route-get-previous-state)

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
   
});
```

But is there **nice** way to parse it into the **url / location** though? For example:

> State: /page/:id/paragraph/:line
>
> Params: id and line, etc..

What I want:

> /page/3/paragraph/5 ...

I mean this could get messy with bunch of *params*. Plus `Angularjs ui-router` could also have `{{ id }}` as params too instead of `:id`. Isn't there a function to do this already or I have to use RegEx? And if so, what is the RegEx string to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$state.href` to get the url:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {

   // $state.href(from, fromParams)

});
```

You can also pass *options* as a third paramerer.
[Read the Docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Not much differently, but you could do:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
});
```

And just store the current. The function there is a lot less to deal with than `$routeChangesuccess`.

Answer (score -2):

using `window.history.back()` will return you to the previous url.