# angular $timeout redirect after 3secs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to redirect back to the previous page using $timeout and $window.history.back(). So when form is submitted a message will show saying (thank you... bla bla) all good from here, but when redirecting back the $timeout doesn't seems to kick in.

```
<div class="thankyou" data-ng-show="vm.hideEnquiryForm">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-x2"></i> Thank you for enquiring, we will get back to you as soon as possible.</h3>
                <a href="javascript:history.back()">Return</a>
        </div>

vm.submitForm = function () {
        enquireService.postEnquireForm(vm)
            .then(function (response) {
                //$location.path(vm.returnUrl);
                //console.log($location.path() + ' '+ vm.returnUrl);

                if (!vm.hideEnquiryForm) {
                    vm.hideEnquiryForm = true;
                }
                $timeout(function () {
                   $window.history.back;
                }, 3000);
            })
    }
```

Comment: Need invocation parens on your call to `.back`

Comment: You should be getting console errors for the .back you used ?

Comment: @JAAulde all good now, I was missing the brackets (). should be $window.history.back();

Answer (score 0):

The are many way to do what you want...

The best way, in my opinion, could be using the interface exposed by your router (assuming that you are using a router)...

this is a useful post based on top of ***UI.Router*** [Angular - ui-router get previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635381/angular-ui-router-get-previous-state), so, you need just to go to the previous state using `$state.go`;

If you cannot do something like that, the only way is using the real `history` object...

```js
vm.submitForm = function () {
  var returnUrl;
  
  enquireService
    .postEnquireForm(vm)
    .then(function (response) {
      var returnUrl = response.returnUrl;
      
      if (!vm.hideEnquiryForm) {
        vm.hideEnquiryForm = true;
      }
    
      return $timeout(window.history.back.bind(window), 3000);
  });
};
```

Comment: Yeah could but I don't see why injecting a new dependency/plugin is necessary just for this simple redirect back. A window.history will do just fine for now, unless there is a big drawback using window.hisotry.back.