# How can I update a variable from an AngularJS view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## What I want

I have 3 views. All views have their own controller. The first view is home. From the home view the user goes to view 2 by clicking on a div element. On view 2 the user opens view 3 by clicking on a button. On view 3 the user clicks on a button and goes back to view 2.

The problem I am facing is that I want to know if the user came from view 2. In that case I want to show different content then when the user came from the home view.

## Create another view

Can it be done without creating another view?

## My try

I created a service that keeps track of if I came from view 3, but the controller of view 2 isn't executed anymore after view 2 got opened from the home view. So basicly `$scope.fromViewThree` isn't updated and still false.

I added `$route.reload()` before `$window.location = "#/app/viewtwo";` because I thought it would reinitialise the controllers([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26504777/4815184)) and then `$scope.fromViewThree` should have been updated. I also tried adding it below `$window.location = "#/app/viewtwo";`.

### Controller view 2

```js
.controller('ViewTwoCtrl', function($scope, $window, fromViewThree) {
    $scope.fromViewThree = fromViewThree.getBoolean();
    fromViewThree.setBoolean(false);
    $scope.goToViewThree = function() {
        $window.location = "#/app/viewthree";
    };
})
```

### Controller view 3

```js
.controller('ViewThreeCtrl', function($scope, $window, fromViewThree) {
    $scope.goToViewTwo = function() {
        fromViewThree.setBoolean(true);
        $window.location = "#/app/viewtwo";
    };
})
```

### Directives.js

```js
.service('fromViewThree', function () {
        var b = false;

        return {
            getBoolean: function() {
                return b;
            },
            setBoolean: function(value) {
                b = value;
            }
        };
})
```

### HTML view 2

```html
<div ng-if="fromViewThree == false">
    <p>You came from view home!</p>
</div>
<div ng-if="fromViewThree == true">
    <p>You came from view three!</p>
</div>
<div>
    <button ng-click="goToViewThree()" ng-if="fromViewThree == false">Go to view 3</button>
    <button ng-click="goToViewThree()" ng-if="fromViewThree == true">Go again to view 3</button>
</div>
```

### HTML view 3

```html
<div class="row">
    <button class='button' ng-click="goToViewTwo()">Lets go to view two!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Manu Antony pushed me in the right direction towards [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)([more info](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)). I added code in app.js which stores the previous state/view name into `$rootScope.fromViewThree`. I can now access the previous state/view name in the HTML of view 2 and the previous state/view name will be updated when switching state/view has been successful.

> Warning:
>
> All scopes inherit from `$rootScope`, if you have a variable
>   `$rootScope.data` and someone forgets that `data` is already defined
>   and creates `$scope.data` in a local scope you will run into problems.

---

## Controller view 2

```
.controller('ViewTwoCtrl', function($scope, $window) {        
    $scope.goToViewThree = function() {
        $window.location = "#/app/viewthree";
    };
})
```

## Controller view 3

```
.controller('ViewThreeCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.goToViewTwo = function() {            
        $window.location = "#/app/viewtwo";
    };
})
```

## Directives.js

I no longer need the service because I use `$rootScope` now to monitor which view is my previous view.

## HTML view 2

```
<div class="row" ng-if="fromViewThree != 'app.viewthree'">
    <p>You came from view home!</p>
</div>
<div class='row' ng-if="fromViewThree == 'app.viewthree'">
    <p>You came from view three!</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <button id="activateCameraBtn" class='button' ng-click="goToViewThree()" ng-if="fromViewThree != 'app.viewthree'">Go to view 3</button>
    <button id="activateCameraBtn" class='button' ng-click="goToViewThree()" ng-if="fromViewThree == 'app.viewthree'">Go again to view 3</button>
</div>
```

## HTML view 3

The HTML for view 3 hasn't changed.

## App.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
        $rootScope.fromViewThree = from.name; //e.g. app.home
    });    
})

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the views and controllers using the [UI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Once you have the states setup, accessing the previous state will be easy [Angular - ui-router get previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635381/angular-ui-router-get-previous-state)

Comment: I have looked at the given answers in the SO question you provided and tried using resolve in the ViewTwo state, but that doesn't seem to work: `resolve: {
                PrevStateName: [
                    "$state",
                    function ($state) {
                        var currentStateData = $state.current.name;
                        return currentStateData;
                    }
                ]
            },` So to be clear resolve does what it needs to do, but not what I need it to do. `PrevStateName` is still `app.home` when coming from view 3 (it should be app.viewthree).

Comment: `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
   //assign the "from" parameter to something
});` is this being broadcast at all?

Comment: No. I added the code inside my 'ViewTwoCtrl' controller and tried `console.log(from);`.