# Going back to previous page and keep changes with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have a products table, I make an advanced research, click on a line to see details and then click on cancel button to go back to the list, all my research input will be empty...

Is it possible to go back where I was ? I mean to my previous research or previous page? 
I'm trying to do this based on ng-models, is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: Please, add some code in order to see what you have done so far, and what you want to do specifically. What you describe can be accomplished in many ways. Cheers!

Comment: May i know which routing you are using. I mean 'ng-route' or 'ui-route'?

Comment: The [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) and the [popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) are used for that. In AngularJS those APIs are uses by [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) in HTML 5 mode.

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro i didn't get over with working solution so i can't post clarify this with code..

Comment: @shubhambahuguna i'm using ui-route

Comment: @slama have you checked  my answer?

Comment: @shubhambahuguna yes, please see my comment below. :)

Comment: @georgeawg by saying previous state, i mean, i don't want to loose my research's result if i consult one row's details and go back to that result.

Comment: Use [AngularJS services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to hold data for life of the application. Use the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to hold data for longer.

Answer (score 0):

these solutions might help you.

[Angular - ui-router get previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635381/angular-ui-router-get-previous-state)

[How do I get the Back Button to work with an AngularJS ui-router state machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247294/how-do-i-get-the-back-button-to-work-with-an-angularjs-ui-router-state-machine)

http://blogs.candoerz.com/question/182248/angular-ui-router-get-previous-state.aspx

more or less same answer in all of these links i found.

```js
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
   //assign the "from" parameter to something
});
```

Comment: it works for to and from but toParams and fromParams are always empty.

Comment: i don't know if i well explained what i want to do or not. in fact i don't want to loose my advanced research's result if i consult a row's details and go back to that result.. you see?